# Automatic casting Vec to array

Tags: arrays, vector, casting, rust

While trying different ways to send a `Vec<u8>` to a function that expects an `&[u8]`, I made a "mistake" which actually works. I wrote some sample code to show this:

```
fn sum(v: &[u8]) -> u8 {
    let mut s = 0u8;
    for x in v.iter() {
        s = s + x;
    }
    return s;
}

fn main() {
    let myarr = [1u8, 2u8, 3u8];
    let myvec = vec![1u8, 2u8, 3u8];

    println!("{}", sum(&myarr));
    println!("{}", sum(&myvec));
}
```

I have a few questions in relation to this:

- Why and how does this work?
- Is there an automatic casting between these two types?
- Does it incur any penalty or it is just taking the memory location of the underlying array of the vector?
- Does this mean that for this type of usage (read only operations on an array of numbers) is better to use an array and not a vector as the API?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's get one thing out of the way: there are **no arrays** in your `sum` function. Rust has three related types, and you can search here on Stack Overflow or *[The Rust Programming Language](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/)* for more information about them:

1. Slices `&[T]`.
2. Vectors `Vec<T>`
3. Arrays `[T; n]`

The `v` argument is a *slice*, which is simply a pointer to a chunk of data and the number of elements.

> Why and how does this work? Is there an automatic casting between these two types?

The [`Deref` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/ops/trait.Deref.html) is coming into play here. There's an implementation of this trait that looks like:

```
impl<T> Deref for Vec<T> {
    type Target = [T];
    fn deref(&self) -> &[T];
}
```

This means that any reference to a `Vec<T>` can act as a reference to a `[T]` and gains all of the methods from the target type. `Deref` is understood by the compiler, but any type is able to implement it, so it's only sort of special.

> Does it incur any penalty or it is just taking the memory location of the underlying array of the vector?

This is a zero-cost transformation, which is why the compiler will do it for you. It's very unusual to have the compiler do anything for you that is expensive.

> Does this mean that for this type of usage it is better to use an array and not a vector as the API?

Absolutely! 100% of the time you should accept a `&[T]` instead of a `&Vec<T>`. More things than just a `Vec` can provide a `&[T]`, and arrays are an example of that.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Nice catch; look at the egg on my face! I only looked at the `sum` function... I've updated the answer to be more clear about that.

Comment: Okay, I honestly wasn't sure whether you had made a mistake, or if my understanding of types in rust was off.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley No way! Believe in yourself! I've got a regular fallible human brain like most of the people on Stack Overflow ^_^

Comment: Is there a good suggestion about the return value of functions? Should they return `[u8]` or `Vec<u8>`, or should they take `Vec<u8>` as an argument?

Comment: @Hernan you can't really return a `[u8]`. Whether you can return a `&[u8]` depends on your case, but that's often more memory-efficient. Other cases use a `Vec<u8>`.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking at the [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) trait in action. If you have a type `T` that implements this trait, and you call a function that takes an argument of type `&U`, then `&T` will call `deref` on the value to make it the right type. The Book has a [chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/deref-coercions.html) about it.

You can see `Vec`'s implementation [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/collections/vec.rs.html#1346-1356) It just copies the `Vec`'s pointer and length fields into a new struct, which is almost free.

And you're right, it's better to write functions that take views rather than owning types. A function that takes a `Vec<u8>` can only be called with a `Vec<u8>`, but a function taking a `&[u8]` can be called with a `Vec<u8>`, a `[u8; 500]`, or `&[u8]` from somewhere else. Similarly, functions should take `&T` rather than `Box<T>` when possible, or `&str` rather than `String`.